# How to use the blacklist method from express-validator

Tags: javascript, validation, express-validator

I have the following `post` request that validates some data:

```js
app.post(
  "/review",
  [
    // Add the middleware to validate email and restaurant info below:
    check("email").isEmail(),
    check("restaurant").notEmpty().blacklist("<>"),
    check("rating").isNumeric(),
    check("review").notEmpty().blacklist("<>")
  ],
// ...
```

The documentation for `validator.js` demonstrates to use the `blacklist` method as follows:

```js
blacklist(input, '\\[\\]')
```

Considering the context of how i'm adding my middleware, it's a bit confusing to understand what exactly should be the `input` parameter. I'm already using the `check` method to look for the input field, what exactly should go in the `blacklist` method?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `[express-validator][1]` which works as a wrapper over `[validator.js][1]`, the input is injected to the `blacklist` method by the `express-validator` and in your case, since you are using `check()` method of `express-validator` the input will be the parameter with the label that you have provided as the argument to `check()` method which might exist in any of the following request objects:

- `req.body`
- `req.cookies`
- `req.headers`
- `req.params`
- `req.query`

In your case for `check("restaurant").notEmpty().blacklist("<>")`, a parameter with the label of `restaurant` will be extract from either one of the aforementioned request objects and  for `check("review").notEmpty().blacklist("<>")`, a parameter with the label `review` will be extracted.

So the only argument that should be provided for the check method is a regex string which specifies the characters that must get removed.